# How can I update attributes of user using UPN of that user , i am using "dn" of that particular user to update the attribute password

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

```
  private static  void modifyAttribute(String userName,LdapContext ctx,DirContext dircontxet,SearchControls searchControls) {
                            try {
                            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results  = ctx.search("dc=germany,dc=pepsi,dc=jp", "uid=" + userName, searchControls);
                            String name ="uid=aman.sahu,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=germany,dc=pepsi,dc=jp";
                            Attributes orig = ctx.getAttributes(name, new String[] { "gidNumber","cn" });
                            ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[2];
                             mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
                                      new BasicAttribute("displayName", "Aman Kumar Sahu"));
                            mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
                                      new BasicAttribute("userPassword", "aman@8989"));
                            ctx.modifyAttributes(name, mods);
                              System.out.println("ATTRvalues"+ctx.getAttributes(name));
                            } 
                            catch (NamingException n) {

                            n.printStackTrace();
                            }
    }
```

I am updating user's attributes by using dn of that user but i want to update the attributes using UPN of that user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP operations require that you reference an entry by its DN and only its DN.